# How to Add Specific Numbers in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

For every instance of "n" or "d12" in a specific range I need to add 11.08, and for every instance of "D" and "E" in that same range I need to add 7.75. I can't figure out how do do this or find anything helpful online, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use COUNTIFS and multiply the result:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"n","d12"}))*11.08+SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"D","E"}))*7.75
```

Comment: I didn't even think of multiplying, thank you so much! This is perfect, thanks for your help